# Break and Continues

Tags: javascript

I wonder if someone can clarify something for me. I have a bit of code to check an array for overlapping values depending on different values. Basically its the contents of a google sheet in rows and comumns for this is specifically GAS. What I have at the moment is

```
  var e = [[2,4,3,4,2],[1,5,3,6,2],[2,4,3,4,1],[1,4,3,6,1],[2,4,3,6,5]];
  var i; //id of entry to check
  var j; //id of element to check
  var k; //id of entry to compare

  for (i in e){ //2D ARRAY ARRAY
      for (k in e){ //ELEMENT TO COMPARE
           if (e[i][2] === e[k][2] && e[i][3] === e[k][3] && e[i][0] && e[i][0] >= e[k][0] && e[i][1] <= e[k][1] && e[i][4] <= e[k][4] &&  i !=k){
             e.splice(i,1);
             continue;
           }
      }
  }
  return e;
```

I had to add the `continue;` as otherwise if the last array checked was also marked for `splice` the code failed. But I assumed `break` would also work in place of continue but for some reason it does not. I thought `break` would return to the outside loop but does it permanently `break` that bit of code?

Thanks people

EDIT: spoke too soon. code still fails even with continue. head scratching continues

Comment: Actually the `continue` is a no op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue` jumps directly to the next iteration, so:

```
  while(true) {
    console.log("a");
    continue;
    console.log("b");
 }
```

will only log `a` as it will jump back to the beginnig of the loop if it reaches continue.If you however move `continue` to the last line of the loop (just as in your code) it does nothing as it would jump to the begining to the loop one line later, so it just skips an empty line.

> I thought break would return to the outside loop

Yup, thats what happens and that is actually a good thing as if you removed the element already, it won't make sense to check for other dupes as you don't want to remove it twice.

Now the real problem is that `splice` changes the indexes, so if you splice out the fourth element, the fith element becomes the fourth element, but the loop continues to the fith element without checking the fourth element again (which is now a different one). Therefore you have to go back by one element before you break:

```
 for(let i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
   for(let k = 0; k < e.length; k++) {
      if(i === k) continue; // < good usecase
      if(/* equality checks */) {
        e.splice(i, 1); // remove the element
        i--; // go back by one as we changed the order
        break; // exit the inner loop
     }
   }
 }
```

---

*IMO:*

1) I would favor `for(const [i, value] of arr.entries()` over `for..in`

2) you will forget what `arr[i][2]` is very soon, giving proper names to the indexes makes it way more readable:

```
  const [idA, someValueA] = e[i];
  const [idB, someValueB] = e[k];
  if(idA === idB && someValueA <= someValueB // ...
```

3) `e` is a bad name.

Comment: Ah. Thats good to know. I think I solved the problem by incrementing k after the splice. Does that seem like its viable? Looks good from my tests? Also is there any advantage to using the long had loop declarations? I used  `for (i in e){` etc just because it seemed neater but will change if thats bad practise.

Comment: @chris 1) incrementing k makes no sense at all, youtlr tests are bad 2) you cant decrement `i` in a `for(i in arr)` loop.

Comment: yep. they are indeed bad! think i need to rewrite it a bit. thanks jonas

Comment: @chris no worries :) glad to help

Comment: I added in your code in place of my `k++` but weirdly its still missing out array. Bit of a head scratcher for a newbie like me

Comment: @chris "missing out an array" ? Have you tried adding a `console.log(i, e[i])` in the outer loop?

Comment: nope. I'm an idiot. works fine! thanks jonas (and everyone else)

Comment: P.S. is `e` bad just because its a temp variable? I'm actually calling the function from the main bit of code so thought that would be OK. Love to know if there is a bit of documentation for the use of `i` `j` `e` etc

Comment: @chris no its bad because no one knows what `e` is. `rows` or `entries` or `table` would be much better names. Imo: The only valid short froms are `x` and `y` for coordinates, `i` for indexes (j,k,l for nested ones) , all other variables should have at least three chars.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a labelled break to break out of nested loops.
eg

```
var num = 0;
outermost:
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < 10 ; j++){
    if(i == 5 && j == 5){
      break outermost;
    }
    num++;
  }
}
```